# Sorting Price using DropDown for Ecommerce Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>E-commerce Website</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on("change", ".price-sorting", function() {
                var sortingMethod = $(this).val();
                if(sortingMethod == 'l2h')
                {
                    sortProductsPriceAscending();
                }
                else if(sortingMethod == 'h2l')
                {
                    sortProductsPriceDescending();
                }
            });            
            function sortProductsPriceAscending() {
                var products = $('.product-item');
                products.sort(function(a, b){ return $(a).data("price-item")-$(b).data("price-item")});
                $(".product-grid").html(products);
            }
            function sortProductsPriceDescending(){
                var products = $('.product-item');
                products.sort(function(a, b){ return $(b).data("price-item") - $(a).data("price-item")});
                $(".product-grid").html(products);
            }
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <!-- Drop down for sorting prices -->
        <select class="price-sorting selectBox" name="price-sorting">
            <option>Relevance</option>  
            <option value="l2h">Price: Low - High</option>  
            <option value="h2l">Price: High - Low</option>
        </select>
        <!-- Products -->
        <div class="product-grid">
            <!-- Product 1 -->
            <div class="product-item">
                <img class="vr_headset_iphone_black" src="https://i1.wp.com/virtualrealitygearreview.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/41gXvNpslJL.jpg?fit=128%2C128">
                <br>
                <span class="vr_headset_item_1">Tepoinn 3D VR Glasses Headset</span>
                <span class="vr_headset_item_2">Virtual Reality Box - Black</span>
                <br>
                <br>
                <span class="price_item">£18.99</span>
                <br>
                <br>
                <button onclick="add-to-basket" class="basket_item style_basket">ADD TO BASKET</button>
            </div>
            <!-- Product 2 -->
            <div class="product-item">
                <img class="vr_headset_iphone_red" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVpLUMNSvaIgOvm5DVg65fap-HzwBEyhJKU23KUCQj5QcUsKuC">
                <br>
                <span class="vr_headset_item_3">Maplin Pro VR Headset with HD</span>
                <span class="vr_headset_item_4">Stereo Headphones - Red</span>
                <br>
                <br>
                <span class="price_item">£39.99</span>
                <br>
                <br>
                <button class="basket_item style_basket">ADD TO BASKET</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am creating an E-commerce website, and I'm trying to sort the products in order of price (Low - High and High - Low). However, the JQuery code I am using does not work. I researched on how to solve this problem, and used an example code posted on this [website](https://medium.com/@ddarrko/easy-product-sorting-using-jquery-17df6a532d62), but the code still does not work for me.
Click here to view code -- [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MuddasarAshfaq/70fnnpw4/2/)

Comment: Your `product-item`s don't have the data attribute you are selecting in `$(a).data("price-item")`. You need to add the data attribute and insert the price as the data-attribute value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `product-item`s should have a `data-price-item` attribute to use to sort, according to your javascript.

You should put that attribute where it belongs

```
<div class="product-item" data-price-item="18.99">
```

Comment: From a quick glance the javascript seems correct. **EDIT**: I checked and it works by modifying just the html.